# Spylon-kernel in Jupyter Notebook raises "Cannot run program "python" error"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to use spylon-kernel to run spark with both python and scala in Jupyter Notebook. I installed python3, spark, Jupyter Notebook, and spylon-kernel in WSL. I configured `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to be `python3`. I ran the following test code in pyspark from command line and it worked fine.

```
lines = sc.textFile("file:///home/.../README.md")
lines.first()
```

But when I ran the same code in Jupyter Notebook with the spylon-kernel using python magic `%%python`, it raised an error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Since Spark can find my python3, I'm suspecting that somehow spylon-kernel cannot. How should I fix this?

Comment: are you  running ```%%python < your code>``` in the same jupyter cell?

Comment: Hi @thePurplePython, yes I am.

Comment: what is the output when you run this in jupyter notebook? ```print(sc.pythonExec); print(sc.pythonVer)```  also have you set ```PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON``` to ```jupyter``` and ```PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS``` to ```notebook```?

Comment: `print(sc.pythonExec)` gives `python` and `print(sc.pythonVer)` gives `3.6`; yes I have set the environment variables as you said when I set up pyspark to be run from jupyter notebook.